# Django dropdown choice selection

Tags: django, dropdown, selection

I would like to create 'dropdown' menu in `template1` with a choice selection. dropdown should list unique dates from the range of `Room` instances `'created_date'` attribute.

Once choice is selected and submitted it should be passed to `template2`. It needs to be passed to template2 so the view that renders template2 can filter Room instances by selected choice and display filtered instances in template2.

Can somebody list for me the required steps I need to complete to do what's written above ? I would read about these required steps so can achieve this task.

Below is my class.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    flat = models.ForeignKey(Flat)
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length= 10)
    room_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
```

I have tried so far to create such dropdown menu and can do it but I do not know how to pass selected choice to template2 so selected choice can be used be the view that renders template2 to filter instances of Room class.

**EDIT**

I have created view, form and template but I have not managed to pass update_date yet.

**views.py**

```
def room_choice(request):
    form = RoomChoiceForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RoomChoiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            room_choice = form.save(commit=False)
            print room_choice
            return redirect('/blocks/all_rooms',request)

    return render(request, 'prostats/choicesform.html',{'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class RoomChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RoomLog
        fields = ('room',)
```

**choicesforms.html**

```
<form method="post" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**url**

```
url(r'^choices/$', views.room_choice, name='choices'),
url(r'^all_rooms/$', views.AllRoomsView.as_view(), name='roomsdetails'),
```

Comment: Could I understand please why I get '-1' with no comment at all so can learn from it and improve my question for future reasons ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the dv was before the edit or not but anytime your asking for a list of steps is essentially a request for free labour since it doesn't show any effort on your part. Having said that, I still find your question unclear as to what part of it you're actually struggling with

Comment: you can use `foreign key` ..... the output is a list and in `HTML` you can use **Bootstrap** elements for create a dropdown section

Comment: I don't understand. I understand I can create dropdown with bootstrap but it does not give me much if do not select data. what should I use fk for ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

1. First step is a form where the user selects some options from a list. The result is something like: `choices=A,B,C`
2. Taking the choices from step 1 (A,B,C) you want to display something based on that selection.

Simply use a regular HTML form with method GET for step 1:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'name-of-url-of-step2' %}">
    <select multiple>
        <option name="choices" value="A"...>
        <option name="choices" value="B"...>
        <option name="choices" value="C"...>
        <option name="choices" value="D"...>
    </select>
</form>
```

Submitting this form will call the url specified in the form `action` with the query string generated from the form fields: `http://.../<url-to-step2>/?choices=A&choices=B` (depending on the selection)

Note that it is normal that the query string will be discarded should there be one in the `action` url, and it will be replaced with the form data.

The Django view that implements step 2 can now read the query parameters: `self.request.GET.getlist('choices')` will return `['A','B']`.